# Race Condition Doesn't happen

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written a bit of code to see the race condition, But it Doesn't happen.

```
class SharedContent:
    def __init__(self, initia_value = 0) -> None:
        self.initial_value = initia_value

    def incerease(self ,delta = 1):
        sleep(1)
        self.initial_value += delta

content = SharedContent(0)
threads: list[Thread] = []
for i in range(250):
    t = Thread(target=content.incerease)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

#wait until all threads have finished their job
while True:
    n = 0
    for t in threads:
        if t.is_alive():
            sleep(0.2)
            continue
        n += 1
    if n == len(threads):
        break
print(content.initial_value)
```

The output is 250 which implies no race condition has happened!
Why is that?

I even tried this with random sleep time but the output was the same.

Comment: Only 250 steps isn't enough to reliably get a race condition, especially since you start them all one at a time. Most, if not all, threads are probably done already even before the next one has started.

Comment: Your method of waiting for all of the threads to finish is... esoteric. Why not simply `join()` each of the threads?

Comment: @mousetail So I changed the number of threads to 1500 and the sleep time to 1.5s but strill no race condition. –

Comment: Maybe try having each thread increment the variable thousands of times or hundreds of thousands of times instead of just one time. Just two threads, each incrementing it a few hundred thousand times is more likely to produce evidence of a collision than a thousand threads that each increment it just once. Also, maybe get rid of the `sleep(1)` call.

Comment: Yea the chance of overlap is still very small. Race conditions are more likely to happen with a small number of threads performing a action over and over than with many threads doing something once.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I don't feel comfortable using join method. It blocks the whole thing which is not my intention. I also modified my code the way you said and still no race condition

Comment: You have to realize that `sleep` has a huge margin of error. The threads will actually increment several milliseconds apart from each-other. Not only that but since the increment happens immediately after wake up the chance of suspension in decreased even more. The chance of a perfect overlap in this case is extremely small. Increasing the number of threads won't help.

Comment: What do you mean, "it blocks the whole thing?" What whole thing? The purpose of `t.join()` is to block the _calling thread_ until thread `t` has finished. The join() call is not supposed to affect any other thread except the thread that calls it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

Comment: @mousetail thanks for explanation. so what can I do to actually see the race condition?

Comment: Try to increment like 10,000 times in a loop in every thread

Comment: @SolomonSlow but if the main thread calls `t.join()` method then it can not start other threads before t finishes.

Comment: @Pexicade Yes you can. Join all the threads at the end

Comment: @mousetail I tried to increment it 100,000 times in a loop. and also removed `sleep(1)` but it didn't happen.

Comment: Keep in mind that Python has a Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) that ensures that even in a multithreaded Python program, only a single thread will ever be running at a given instant.  A side effect of that is that race conditions may be (inadvertently?) avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your program. This version prints a different number every time I run it.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from threading import Thread

class SharedContent:
    def __init__(self, initia_value = 0) -> None:
        self.initial_value = initia_value

    def incerease(self ,delta = 1):
        for i in range(0, 1000000):
            self.initial_value += delta

content = SharedContent(0)
threads = []
for i in range(2):
    t = Thread(target=content.incerease)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

#wait until all threads have finished their job
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print(content.initial_value)
```

What I changed:

- Only two threads instead of 250.
- Got rid of `sleep()` calls.
- Each thread increments the variable one million times instead of just one time.
- Main program uses `join()` to wait for the threads to finish.

Comment: when I run it I get 2000000 output!!

Comment: Re, "when I run it..."  Can't help you there. Maybe you are running a different version of Python than I. (I ran it under Python 3.8.9)  Maybe you are running a different operating system. (I am running MacOS 12.5.1.) Maybe your computer has a different processor than mine. (Mine is an Apple M1.) Maybe... Maybe... Maybe... If a program obeys all of the rules of multi-threading, then it is supposed to work. But, if it _breaks_ the rules, nothing guarantees that it won't work anyway. It's more a matter of luck.